# How to keep hidden sheets hidden after someone makes a copy?

Tags: google-sheets, privacy

I have a Google spreadsheet with multiple sheets : one for input and others for formulas. These other sheets are hidden and the formulas not meant to be edited/seen.

The goal is to have many people making copies and providing various inputs, while the hidden sheets remain hidden.
If I make them editors, they can make a copy but have free access over it after. I also tried using the ImportRange function, but it only works when using the original spreadsheet and not with copies.

Is there any way, maybe via a script or whatever else, to prevent the access to the hidden sheets while allowing the math to be done from the first sheet inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can NOT. Period.

Once someone makes a copy (since they have edit rights). It is theirs to keep and do whatever they like.

In your case though, you could probably try a combination of Google Forms (for the input), Google Sheets (where the answers land from the form and calculations get executed) and have just the resulting fields of the spreadsheet on a site/page for everyone with the link to view.

> EDIT (as per OP's comment)

You do not need to build a site or page to share the results.
All you need is the sheet URL with `?rm=minimal` appended to the end of it, i.e.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxx/edit?rm=minimal

Comment: Thanks from the quick answer, and the confirmation this is not doable using only google sheets. I have no experience on how to make a site so they can see the results, any small explanation/guide/link would help so I can figure it out!
Else, I know I can make it work using Excel, but it's far less convenient than sharing a link.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Nice, had no idea about this feature. However, I'll have to think about how to make a new sheet with one row per inputs+results, as if I only add ?rm=minimal, it'll only display the results from the last input. Or can it create one "view" sheet per input so it doesnt get mixed up between people?
EDIT : input from formulas are like "B4", so not sure how to use each answer rows accordingly.

Comment: _" Or can it create one "view" sheet per input so it doesn't get mixed up between people?"_.  That will be done after manipulating the replies and doing the calculations on the sheet. But that is a completely different story.